# Apache serves only the default virtualhost, ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, virtual-host

When I type

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*
```

I see

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myserver
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mydomain1.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomain1.net/public/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain1.net
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.mydomain1.net/$1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.yasser.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomain2.com/public/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain2.com
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.mydomain2.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

When I browse mydomain1.com and mydomain2.com, I see the contents from "myserver" which is list of directories in `/var/www`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also here is the output of `apachectl -S`:

```
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server myserver (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myserver:1)
     port 80 namevhost myserver (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myserver:1)
     port 80 namevhost www.mydomain1.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mydomain1.net:1)
     port 80 namevhost mydomain1.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mydomain1.net:6)
     port 80 namevhost www.mydomain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mydomain2.com:1)
     port 80 namevhost mydomain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.mydomain2.com:6)
```

Comment: Put your myserver at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please use

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.example.org/
```

When doing a redirect of *everything*.

Also make sure that *all* your vhosts' `ServerName`s and `ServerAlias`es are resolving correctly, both on the server and on the client.

Could you also post the output of

```
curl -Lv http://example.com/
```

here, so we can see what's going on, exactly?

Comment: The problem was that the server couldn't resolve the hostnames